# Is there a way to simplify multiple list comprehensions?

Tags: python, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have in my code something like this:

```
mean_realp = [[df[(df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)]['P'].mean()                                          for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
mean_setp = [[df[(df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)]['pressure setpoint [mbar]'].mean()                    for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
stddev_realp = [[df[(df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)]['P'].std()                                         for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
stddev_pbefore = [[df[(df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)]['Pbefore [mbar]'].std()                          for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
maxes_realp = [[df[(df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)]['P'].max()                                          for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
mins_realp = [[df[(df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)]['P'].min()                                           for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
```

Is there a way to simplify this, without using outside loops? I don't have anything against them, but there must be a more elegant solution...

For the latter part

```
for v in uvpwms] for w in upwms]
```

I can't think of anything simpler than outside loops.

But what about the inner part, the selections. Is there some simpler solution (e.g. lambda expression)?

Comment: use pandas.Groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a helper function to emphasize and parametrize the differences. This is a start, and you should probably find a more suitable name that ties better into what the dataset really represents:

```
def transformMatrix(matrix, label, transformer):
    return [[df[transformer((df['fvpwm'] == v) & (df['gppwm'] == w)][label]) for v in matrix] for w in matrix]

mean_realp = transformMatrix(upwms, 'P', lambda elements: elements.mean())
mean_setp = transformMatrix(upwms, 'pressure setpoint [mbar]', lambda elements: elements.mean())
stddev_realp = transformMatrix(upwms, 'P', lambda elements: elements.std())
stddev_pbefore = transformMatrix(upwms, 'Pbefore [mbar]', lambda elements: elements.std())
maxes_realp = transformMatrix(upwms, 'P', lambda elements: elements.max())
mins_realp = transformMatrix(upwms, 'P', lambda elements: elements.min())
```